# Creating terms in WordPress custom taxonomy

Tags: wordpress

I have a created a custom post type Properties and within that I have created a custom Taxonomy called Position and within that I want to create some terms I have created the term Slider using the code below and that works fine.

```
function realestatepro_custom_terms() {

    wp_insert_term(
      'Slider', // the term 
      'Position', // the taxonomy
          array(
            'description'=> 'Will be featured in the home page slider.',
            'slug' => 'home-page-slider'
          )
    );


}

add_action( 'init', 'realestatepro_custom_terms' );
```

But I want to create more terms, like Featured and Promoted, but I am not sure how, I did consider just repeating the whole wp_insert_terms block but that doesn't seem right, then I tried to just add another term straight after the first one but that just didn't work.

Anyone know the best way to add multiple terms?

Comment: There should be an interface in the WordPress admin for you to add terms to the taxonomy.

Comment: @JamesJones I want to do it programmatically so the terms are their when the theme is installed.

Answer (score 3):

`wp_insert_term()` is a big function with a lot of cleaning, actions and error checking. There isn't a version of it that repeats. So you'll have to wrap `wp_insert_term()` into a `foreach` loop.

```
function realestatepro_custom_terms() {

    $terms = array(
      'Slider' => array(
        'description'=> 'Will be featured in the home page slider.',
        'slug' => 'home-page-slider'
      ),
      'Featured' => array( /*properties*/ 
      ),
      'Promoted' => array( /*properties*/ 
      )
    );
    foreach($terms as $term => $meta){
        wp_insert_term(
          $term, // the term 
          'Position', // the taxonomy
          $meta
        );
    }
}
add_action( 'init', 'realestatepro_custom_terms' );
```

Another possibility is you could use `wp_set_object_terms()` like this:

```
$terms = array( 'Featured', 'Promoted', 'Slider');
wp_set_object_terms( $object_id, $terms, 'Position' );
```

where `$object_id` is a dummy Properties post you create. After adding the terms you could delete the post. The problem here is that you can't set any of the term meta like the slug or description. Furthermore the `wp_set_object_terms()` function simply contains a `foreach` loop with `wp_insert_term()` repeated similar to the first solution. It's nothing too spectacular. I don't really recommend this second option, just mentioning for interest.